# windows batch script saving absolute paths to text file

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, path, absolute

I currently have the following folder structure:

```
Root\img\test\   this folder contains my image files
Root\eval\color\ this folder contains folders, each of these folders contains a random number of files, some of which share the same name with the images(but with .seg extension)
```

What I'm trying to do is to create in the first location, for each image, a corresponding text file, with the same name, which contains the absolute paths to every file that has the same name in the second location.
Currently this is what I have so far:

```
for %A in (*.jpg) do for /R ../../eval\color %i in (*.seg) do echo %~fi >> %~dpA%~ni.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work for you.

```
@echo off
pushd "Root\img\test\"
for %%a in (*.*) do (
dir "Root\eval\color\%%~na.*" /b /s /a-d >>"%%~na.txt"
)
popd
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for %r "Root\img\test" %a in (*.jpg) do (echo(%~fa)>"%~dpna.txt"
```